# Interesting cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 and cosine values

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, nested-radicals

It is interesting to note that any angle between 45° to 90° satisfying $1\over4$ < $p \over q$ <$1\over2$ where $ p \over q$ is of form $p = 2^n $ and $q$ is an odd number satisfying $2^{n+1} <q <2^{n+2}$ can be represented as cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 (Hereafter referred as $cin\sqrt2$) [refer here for an example of interesting cyclic infinite nested radical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932921/interesting-infinite-nested-square-roots-of-2-for-2-cos1-and-2-sin1)

> **Let us consider certain cosine angles with odd numbers starting from 5 and its exponents and see the number of $'+'$ and $'-'$ signs in single cycle**

$2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})=\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{4\pi}{5}})=\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{5}})=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5}}})$. We can observe expansion goes infinite and results in cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 for $2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})$ or $2\cos72^\circ$

**$2\cos\frac{2\pi}{5} = cin\sqrt2[1-1+]$ single cycle contains $1 -$ sign and $1 +$ sign and is simple representation of $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+...}}$**

$2\cos(\frac{8\pi}{25}) = \sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{16\pi}{25}}) = \sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{9\pi}{25}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{18\pi}{25}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{7\pi}{25}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{14\pi}{25}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{11\pi}{25}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{22\pi}{25}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{3\pi}{25}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{6\pi}{25}}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{12\pi}{25}}}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{24\pi}{25}}}}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{25}}}}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{25}}}}}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{4\pi}{25}}}}}}}}}}) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{8\pi}{25}}}}}}}}}}})$

Above cycle repeats infinitely

$2\cos\frac{8\pi}{25} = cin\sqrt2[4-2+1-3+]$ single cycle contains $5 +$ signs and $5 -$ signs and is simple representation of $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}}}}}}}}$

**Steps can be simplified as follows.**

1. When the angle exceeds $\frac{\pi}{2}$ we are applying the basic cosine angle identity $2\cos(\pi-\theta) = -2\cos(\theta)$
2. Doubling happens infinitely with $\frac{\pi}{4} < \theta < \pi$
3. As the denominator in the angle is odd number, when the $\frac{numerator}{denominator} > \frac{1}{2}$ the signs changes while doubling the cosine angle expansion as nested radical.

Above steps are programmable.

I have created a program to calculate the number of $'+'$ and $'-'$ signs in cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 for cosine values in Python as follows and anyone can verify which will provide the result for any odd number other than 3 (I am not expert in this)

```
import time
n = int(input("Enter an odd number to get single cycle cinsqrt2 ")) #odd number is denominator
# steps to calculate numerator as $2^n$ so that fraction lies between 0.25 and 0.5
i = 0
for i in range(n):
    if 2 ** i > n and n < 2 ** (i + 1):
        break
numerator = 2 ** (i - 2)
print("Numerator is", numerator)
#print("The Angle generated is", (numerator*180)/n, (numerator*180)//n,'+', ((numberator*180)%n)/n)
halfway_of_n = (n - 1) // 2 #to decide the sign, we need halfway number
# print("Half way to n is", halfway_of_n)
lst = []
r = numerator * 2
begin = time.time()
while r != numerator:
    if r > halfway_of_n:
        r = n - r
        r = r * 2
        lst = lst + ['-']

    else:
        r = r * 2
        lst = lst + ['+']
lst = lst + ['+']
print(len(lst))
count = lst.count('-')
print('No of minus signs is/are ', count)
count = lst.count('+')
print('No of plus signs is/are ', count)
print(lst) #list containing '+' and '-' signs

end = time.time()

print('Program execution time is', end - begin)
```

$2\cos\frac{32\pi}{125} = cin\sqrt2[2-4+1-1+1-2+2-1+2-1+1-1+2-2+3-1+3-3+1-2+1-1+5-1+1-5+]$ single cycle contains $25 +$ signs and $25 -$ signs and (representing this as a infinite nested radical will be big and occupy big space. Therefore I'm representing in the simplified form as shown above)

**Exciting pattern emerges for cosine values having exponent of 5 in the denominator and number of + and - signs in the $cin\sqrt2$ which also exponentially growing as follows**

> for $5^1$ in denominator $5^0 + 5^0$ signs in total (in single cycle)

> for $5^2$ in denominator  $5^1 + 5^1$ signs in total (in single cycle)

> for $5^3$ in denominator  $5^2 + 5^2$ signs in total (in single cycle)

> for $5^4$ in denominator  $5^3 + 5^3$ signs in total (in single cycle)

and so on

**Question:**
Any other way to get these signs inside the nested radicals in a better way?

Comment: "reward an existing answer" when there's no answer ? You must have chosen the wrong option when filling the bounty form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Main Question(s)

I'd like to generalize the setup of the [OP](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OP#5393886) a bit, and strip out some of the context to focus on the main idea.

#### Setup

Let $q>2$ be an odd integer and let $p$ be an integer with $0<p<\dfrac{q}2$.

Then note that $0<\cos\left(\dfrac{p\pi}{q}\right)$. We can use a version of the [cosine half angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) to find that $2\cos\left(\dfrac{p\pi}{q}\right)=\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\dfrac{2p\pi}{q}\right)}$. If $2p>\dfrac{q}2$, the inner cosine is no longer positive; in that case, we can first use $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$ to write $2\cos\left(\dfrac{2p\pi}{q}\right)=-2\cos\left(\dfrac{(q-2p)\pi}{q}\right)$, and have $\cos\left(\dfrac{(q-2p)\pi}{q}\right)>0$.

This means that, for $0<p_1<\dfrac{q}2$, we can choose $0<p_2<\dfrac{q}2$ so that $2\cos\left(\dfrac{p_1\pi}{q}\right)=\sqrt{2\pm2\cos\left(\dfrac{p_2\pi}{q}\right)}$ where we have a $+$ sign and $p_2=2p_1$ if $2p_1<\dfrac{q}2$ and we have a $-$ sign and $p_2=q-2p_1$ otherwise. Repeating this step gives rise to a "$p$ sequence": $p_1,p_2,\ldots$.

But by doing calculations, it seems empirically that all the sequences for a given $q$ and starting $p$ are actually *periodic*, which would mean that we can *always* write $2\cos\left(\dfrac{p\pi}{q}\right)$ as a [nested radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical) of the form described above, with $2\cos\left(\dfrac{p\pi}{q}\right)$ on the inside (suggesting a sort of [infinite nesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Square_roots)).

For example, with $q=17$ and an initial $p=8$, we obtain $$2\cos\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{17}\right)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{17}\right)}}}}$$

#### Questions

1. Is the sequence of $p$ values guaranteed to be periodic (so that we can always write these cosines as these special nested radicals)?
2. When it is periodic, is there another way to find/understand the pattern of $+$ and $-$ signs in the [radical expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root)?

### Main Answers

#### Answer 1

Yes, under our assumption that $q$ is odd, the sequence of $p$ values is guaranteed to be periodic. Note that if $q$ is not odd, then this would not be guaranteed as in the calculation of $2\cos(1^\circ)=2\cos\left(\dfrac{1\pi}{180}\right)$ from [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3932921/26369).

#### Answer 2

Starting with $p$, the sequence of $+$/$-$ signs can be written with the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), borrowing `%` from [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-68), as follows:
$$n^\text{th}\text{ sign}=\begin{cases}
+ & \text{ if }\left(2^{n}p\right)\%\left(2q\right)<\dfrac{q}{2}\\
+ & \text{ if }\left(2^{n}p\right)\%\left(2q\right)>\dfrac{3q}{2}\\
- & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

We can also phrase this in an equivalent and suggestive way using [quadrants of the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)) and [the standard position of angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Positive_and_negative_angles) greater than $2\pi$.
$$n^\text{th}\text{ sign}=\begin{cases}
+ & \text{ if }\dfrac{2^{n}p\pi}{q}\text{ is in Quadrant I or IV}\\
- & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Using $+1$ and $-1$ to represent the signs, and the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), this is equivalent to
$$n^\text{th}\text{ sign}=\mathop{\mathrm{sgn}}\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{2^{n}p\pi}{q}\right)\right)$$

#### Proof of 1

Even without our assumption that $q$ is odd, since there are only finitely many values that the $p$s can take on, the sequence must be [*eventually* periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence#Generalizations) by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

But if $q$ is odd, the sequence is guaranteed to be periodic. It may be easiest to show this using some facts about [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)).

Let $G_q$ be the [multiplicative group of integers modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) $q$. Then we can quotient out by the $2$-element subgroup represented by $\{1,-1\}$ to get a new group $G_q^*$, with elements of the form $[n]$ where $0<n<q/2$ and $n$ is relatively prime to $q$. Since $q$ is odd, $2$ is a representative of an element of $G_q$, and hence $G_q^*$. And since $p$ and $q$ only appear in a fraction, we can assume [WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, so that $[p]\in G_q^*$.

Since $[2]$ generates a subgroup of the finite group $G_q^*$, the sequence $[p],[2][p],[2]^2[p],\ldots$ must be periodic. But note that if $[n]\in G_q^*$, then $[2][n]=[2n]=[-2n]=[q-2n]$, so that the smallest positive representatives of $[p],[2][p],[2]^2[p],\ldots$ are exactly the terms of the original $p$ sequence.

#### Proof of 2

Note that the first sign for $p$ corresponds to $\mathop{\mathrm{sgn}}\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{2p\pi}{q}\right)\right)$, and then for the next sign we start from a new value of $p$ based on that sign. By the $2\pi$ periodicity of $\cos$ and the denominator of $q$ in $\cos\left(\dfrac{m\pi}{q}\right)$, the signs can only depend on $(2^np)\%(2q)$.

Certainly, if $(2^np)\%(2q)<\dfrac{q}{2}$, then the residue $r=(2^np)\%(2q)$ of $2^np$ modulo $2q$ is the same as the residue modulo $q$; and this residue is small enough that there is no $q-r$ step needed, so the sign is $+1$.

Similarly, if $\dfrac{q}{2}<(2^np)\%(2q)<q$, then the residue $r$ of $2^np$ modulo $2q$ is the same as the residue modulo $q$; but this residue is large enough we have a $q-r$ step and the sign is $-1$.

And if $\dfrac{3q}{2}<(2^np)\%(2q)$, then if $R,r$ are the residues modulo $2q,q$, respectively, we have $R-q=r$. And since $R>\dfrac{3q}{2}$, $r>\dfrac{q}2$, so that we are dealing with $q-r=q-(R-q)=2q-R<\dfrac{q}{2}$. Thus, the sign is $+1$.

Similarly, if $q<(2^np)\%(2q)<\dfrac{3q}{2}$, then the sign is $-1$.

### Context

I'd like to share how I found references covering these results, and some other related facts about this construction. For $q=25$, I noted the $p$ sequence (starting from $p=1$ instead of $p=8$) $1,2,4,8,9_{=25-16},7,11,3,6,12,1,\ldots$. If you search [Sloane's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloane%27s) for [1,2,4,8,9,7](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C8%2C9%2C7), you find just one sequence: [A334430](http://oeis.org/A334430). This sequence basically lists the all the $p$ sequences ("cycles") for all the odd $q$, except that they start cycles at *twice* the lowest number of the cycle, by convention. The $1$, in "$1,2,4,8,9,7$", that was found was actually the end of the sole cycle for $q=23$, not the beginning of a cycle for $q=25$.

#### References

The page for [A334430](http://oeis.org/A334430) mentions and links many relevant texts, including (in chronological order of first publication):

- "Polygons and Chaos" by Jay Kappraff and Gary W. Adamson, published in [Journal of Dynamical Systems and Geometric Theories](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/1726037X.2004.10698481) and earlier in the freely-available proceedings of the [Bridges conference](http://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2001/bridges2001-67.html)
- [Trigonometrie und unterhaltsame Zahlentheorie](https://books.google.com/books/about/Trigonometrie_und_unterhaltsame_Zahlenth.html?id=LDVjAAAACAAJ) by Carl Schick ([Table of Contents scan](https://d-nb.info/970616686/04) provided by [Deutsche Nationalbibliothek](http://d-nb.info/970616686).
- [A Mathematical Tapestry: Demonstrating the Beautiful Unity of Mathematics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/mathematical-tapestry/18B78FD8A22C898D438A4879EAD2619C) by Peter Hilton and Jean Pedersen
- "Modified Congruence Modulo $n$ with Half The Amount of Residues" by Tim Beyne and Gerold Brändli ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.02757))
- "On the Equivalence of Three Complete Cyclic Systems of Integers" by Wolfdieter Lang ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04300))

The above approach to proving periodicity came from sections 3.1 and 3.2 of [Beyne and Brändli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.02757). And the proof of the sign pattern was a direct adaptation of the proof of Lemma 19 in [Lang](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04300).

#### mod* Congruence

Building on the work of Schick, [Beyne and Brändli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.02757) investigate properties of the group $G_n^*$, where we consider integers $a,b$ to be congruent $(\mathrm{mod}^*n)$ if $a-b$ or $a+b$ is a multiple of $n$. Many theorems and conjectures of elementary number theory carry over from $\mathrm{mod}$ to $\mathrm{mod}^*$

#### Period length

One missing ingredient to finding the exact sign sequence for a single period of the $p$ sequence is the length of the period. Otherwise, it's not clear when to cut off the infinite sign sequence from answer 2 above. This period is mentioned in all 5 references above, and is [A003558](http://oeis.org/A003558). It could be written "the order of $[2]$ in $G_q^*$" or "the least number $m>0$ such that $2^m\equiv\pm1\pmod q$".

#### Cosine Polynomials

Rather than turning a nested radical representation into an infinite one, we can use it to find a polynomial that a given cosine value is a root of. For example, $$2\cos\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{17}\right)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{17}\right)}}}}$$ means that $2\cos\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{17}\right)$ is a root of $x=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}$, and hence of $\left(\left(\left(2-x^{2}\right)^{2}-2\right)^{2}-2\right)^{2}-2=x$. Rewriting, it is a zero of $x^{16}- 16x^{14}+ 104x^{12}- 352x^{10}+ 660x^8 - 672x^6+ 336x^4- 64x^2 +x+2$.

Unfortunately, this is not the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)) for $2\cos\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{17}\right)$. That would be $x^8-x^7-7x^6+6x^5+15x^4-10x^3-10x^2+4x+1$, whose coefficients are listed in [A136571](http://oeis.org/A136571). Minimal polynomials for the cosines whose $p$ sequence contains $1$ are discussed in [Lang](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04300), as well as its reference "The field $\bf \mathbb Q(2\, cos\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{\pi}}{n}\right))$, its Galois group, and length ratios in the regular $\bf n$-gon" ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1018)), also by Lang.

Comment: That is great. It is an amazing work and references. **Angle outside the range $\frac{\pi}{4} to \frac{\pi}{2}$ have cyclic infinite component and acyclic finite component to represent as nested radical.** I have published in the same forum. Thank you very much